# Combine duplicate nodes in Monte Carlo tree search

Tags: monte-carlo

I'm implementing Monte Carlo tree search for educational purposes and am wondering whether it is useful to combine duplicate states during execution to reduce tree size. Is there some efficient algorithm to accomplish this? I haven't found much about this on the internet -- is this something unusual?

Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is common, but we do not merge states but simply omit duplicates when traversing. Usually it's done by keeping a hash table of visited states,  to guarantee an amortized constant time of insert and lookup.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad so the idea is basically to check if a node already exists and add it as a child node? I've read papers such as [this excellent comparision of MCTS variations](http://www.cameronius.com/cv/mcts-survey-master.pdf) but I am simply overwhelmed by the variety of choices to speed up MCTS. Of course I want to implement "basic" stuff like UCT, but from there on it just seems like guesswork how to create the fastest algorithm and the usual answer seems to be "it depends on the domain". Are there any definite recommendations one should include?

Comment: So far I have found [Beam Monte Carlo tree search](https://dke.maastrichtuniversity.nl/m.winands/documents/CIG2012_paper_32.pdf) promising and I will try to implement this once my basic MCTS algorithm is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically referred to as using a "transposition table" and can be useful to share rollout data between branches. However, it can introduce issues with UCT algorithm.

This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50194982/13719652 explains the possible issues with UCT, with the top answer offering an amended version of the UCT algorithm to use with transposition tables.